# When I get Java Libraries how would I use them and use it in Java?

Tags: java, libraries, lwjgl, slick2d

I got LWJGL and Slick2D because it says that they're libraries to make it simpler to make games. Once I installed them do I just read the documentation and learn what everything means or do I have to learn it in-depth somewhere else? I'm pretty new to Java and want to start learning the libraries and everything.

Comment: Before you start learning to use libraries you need to learn the Java language first. Pretty much every library for any language assumes you have some understanding of how the language itself works, so just reading the docs would be frustrating. Start small and learn Java first, then build up from there.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries are groups of classes which can be imported. E.g. import java.util.*; will import everything in the util library of the java library. If you are unsure of what the libraries contain you can check their java docs. Assuming they have one made. Here is the slick2d one: http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/

Hope this helps. Not really sure what else to say :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Study the Java language well!
2. Study the Java language classes (such as Collection Framework, Execution Framework...) well!
3. Study your library in depth.

Otherwise you would find yourself reinventing the wheel again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't dig into game programming just yet, learn about java first, and when you comfortable with that, work your way into slick and lwgjl

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you need to follow these lectures: http://www.academicearth.org/lectures/programming-methodology-intro

Once you've done them you'll have a good understanding of Java. That course shows you how to use a library called the ACM library. It's a learning library, really helpful.

Once you've done that, you can read a book that I wrote on Slick2D. You can buy it from Amazon: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Game-Programming-Book-Intermediate/dp/1475169175/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1346545025&sr=1-1

That's the UK link but it's also available throughout Europe and in the US and Canada.

/shameless self-advertising

Anyway, those lectures will teach you Java at a basic level, and that's really a good place to be. It's free Ivy League College education, and nobody can argue with that. It's really simple to understand too.